# Rearranging a singly linked list

Tags: python, singly-linked-list, reorderlist

I am having trouble understanding part of a solution to a question I found online.

Given the head of a Singly LinkedList, write a method to modify the LinkedList such that the nodes from the second half of the LinkedList are inserted alternately to the nodes from the first half in reverse order. So if the LinkedList has nodes 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> null, your method should return 1 -> 6 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4 -> null.

Your algorithm should not use any extra space and the input LinkedList should be modified in-place.

Here is my solution, which is quite similar to the original one.

```
from __future__ import print_function


class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next

  def print_list(self):
    temp = self
    while temp is not None:
      print(str(temp.value) + " ", end='')
      temp = temp.next
    print()


def reorder(head):
  if head is None or head.next is None:
    return

  slow, fast = head, head

  while fast is not None and fast.next is not None:
    slow = slow.next
    fast = fast.next.next

  head_second_half = reverse(slow)
  head_first_half = head

  while head_first_half is not None and head_second_half is not None:
    temp = head_first_half.next
    head_first_half.next = head_second_half
    head_first_half = temp

    temp = head_second_half.next
    head_second_half.next = head_first_half
    head_second_half = temp

  if head_first_half is not None:
    head_first_half.next = None

def reverse(head):
  previous = None

  while head is not None:
    _next = head.next
    head.next = previous
    previous = head
    head = _next

  return previous


def main():
  head = Node(2)
  head.next = Node(4)
  head.next.next = Node(6)
  head.next.next.next = Node(8)
  head.next.next.next.next = Node(10)
  head.next.next.next.next.next = Node(12)
  reorder(head)
  head.print_list()


main()
```

What was giving me the most trouble was the second while loop in `reorder`. I had the concept of doing the following...

```
temp = head_first_half.next
head_first_half.next = head_second_half
head_first_half = temp
```

and so on...

The answer is correct only once I set the next of the last node to `None` in

```
if head_first_half is not None:
  head_first_half.next = None
```

However, I had to take a sneak peek at the solution to get this part. Once going through this problem more carefully on paper I noticed that I might not even understand what I wrote myself in the second while loop In `reorder`. What I believe is going on is the following...

First Iteration

```
temp -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> None
head_first_half -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> None
and the current linked list: 2 -> 12 -> 10 -> 8 -> None

temp -> 10 -> 8 -> None
head_second_half -> 10 -> 8 -> None
and the current linked list: 2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> None
```

Second Iteration

```
temp -> 6 -> 8 -> None
head_first_half -> 6 -> 8 -> None
and the current linked list: 2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10 -> 8 -> None

temp -> 8 -> None
head_second_half -> 8 -> None
and the current linked list: 2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10 -> 6 -> 8 -> None
```

Third Iteration

```
temp -> 8 -> None
head_first_half -> 8 -> None
and the current linked list: 2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10 -> 6 -> 8 -> None

temp -> None
head_second_half -> None
and the current linked list: 2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10 -> 6 -> 8 -> 8 -> None
```

because, `head_second_half is None` while loop ends.
Then, check if `head_first_half is not None` then `head_first_half.next = None`

In the third iteration I do not see how we have a result that ends up as...

```
2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10 -> 6 -> 8 -> None
```

From what I can see the 8 points back to itself because in the third iteration

```
head_first_half -> 8 -> None
```

and by doing

```
head_second_half.next = head_first_half
```

I figured that `head_second_half.next == None` and the previous node before that is `8` but now with `head_first_half`, then `head_second_half.next` points to `8 -> None`. I know we are not duplicating anything in our linked list so what I can make sense out of is that if `8 -> None` from `head_first_half` is not a separate linked list but just a pointer that points to `8 -> None`, then, we do not have a cycle here. However, If this is not right (my thinking) then shouldn't we have a cycle then?

also why on earth would we have to do the last if statement in `reorder`?

Comment: It will be beneficial to link to the source question and solution

Comment: Can’t it’s a subscription based site. I am just using it to study